# Git Push ERROR: Repository not found

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am having a very strange problem with `git` and `github`. When I try and push, I am getting:

```
git push -u origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I added the remote:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:account-name/repo-name.git
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes that is how I got the `git remote add origin git@github.com:account-name/repo-name.git`. It exists in GitHub, and its a private repo.

Comment: Well I don't see anything you're specifically doing wrong. Have you got any other similar repositories that work? Have you contacted GitHub support?

Comment: did you double check your user and repo names?

Comment: did u change your github user name

Comment: none of the 10 answers below have worked for you?

Comment: Any chance this is related to the read/write permissions on the repo? I have a read only repo and I get this message when I try to push something

Comment: I was so convinced that I had read-write access to the project since I could check it out. Also the sibling project I could also read-write. But @Michael is right:
My problem is ````write permission````!
My setup is:  
- I have my own github account  
- I work on an another account's (lets call it companyX) project a w/ read-write  
- problem: I work on another companyX account's project where I only had read access.  
  
...Did cost me a couple of hours...

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it by updating the .git/config file. I put the username in the URL key of `[remote "origin"]` section.

Comment: Just add your git usernane with your repo somthing like https://myusername@github.com/youruserusername/yourrepo.git 

edit file ./.git/config and put username in url like mentioned above now when you run run your git push it will ask you for password  

this happens because maybe from other repo you have globally saved username and password which cached and your current repo uses different git account

Comment: For those who are not familiar with the command line, I suggest downloading and installing [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) which can help with that. Good luck!

Comment: I tried everything for 5,6 hours. It was the problem with the write permission in my case.

Answer (score 764):

Check to see if you have read-write access.

The Git error message is misleading. I had a similar issue. I had been added to an existing project. I cloned it and committed a local change. I went to push and got the `ERROR: Repository not found.` error message.

The person who added me to the project gave me read-only access to the repository. A change by them and I was able to push.

Comment: Gotta love those useful Git error messages.  Can't find the repository that I just cloned from, huh?  Liar.

Comment: yep same problem here--no commit rights and you get this very obfuscated error message <sigh>

Comment: Thankyou! You can check this by viewing the project on the web and clicking on "New File"

Comment: For how to check which permissions you have to a repository, check [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21006487/854151) (to a different question).

Comment: So for me, my password had a ` (tick) in it and PhpStorm was removing the character before sending the git push:

Lets say for this example my password is `_pa``ssword_`

Phpstorm would output the following:

`https://_username_:_password_@github.com/_username_/repo.git`

instead of 

`https://_username_:_pa``ssword_@github.com/_username_/repo.git`

Changed password to something not using the ` character. WORKS!!!

Comment: Had a similar problem. One of the repos i had the write access previously, but some one has changed the permission and took a while to figure out what happened.

Comment: This is it. I was using a personal access token to log in to GitHub. but I hadn't granted the right permissions while creating the token. The error message is quite misleading

Comment: Sometimes if you use many accounts on your system. there might be an issue of you forgetting to register your key with `ssh-agent`. run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/{Key name}` to register key with `ssh-agent`.

Comment: The solution does not work for me. I created and used a github token with EVERY possible permission.

Comment: If you have a saved personal access token being used to authenticate to the repo, and it is expired, it will show this error. Check ~/git-credentials and delete if necessary.

Comment: I had read-write access but wasn't using my ssh key. After I generated ssh keys with my email and added them to GitHub, I was able to push. To generate ssh keys - `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Answer (score 346):

I had the same problem, with a private repo.

do the following:

remove the remote origin

```
git remote rm origin
```

re-add the origin but with your username and pwd with writing privileges on this pvt repo

```
git remote add origin  https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

Comment: What if the password has @?

Comment: @AnupamChugh you need to replace '@' with '%40' in your password. Basically you can check by running JS code `encodeURIComponent(password)`

Comment: And I recommend using SSH instead of https, because especially for GitHub, using https will require additional step if you enabled 2FA.

Comment: I recommend using a credential helper rather than storing your password in plain text: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: I renamed the repo. `git remote rm origin` and adding repo usual way without password helped me.

Comment: Finally! The catch is for the PRIVATE REPO. This worked if you have a Private Repo and gettting this error by following Git hub instructions to push an existing repo from local in Xcode to remote in Github:

`$ git push -u origin master

remote: Repository not found.

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/teksunios/Abc.git/' not found`

Comment: Remember to encode your password eg use PHP `echo urlencode('p+b/&6git67hub?p#t[$Trb%');` to encode your password

Comment: this can also happen if the repo was pulled using an oauth token for a different user account than you usually use, and now you're trying to push using your usual account.  this fix (or a similar `git remote add origin git@github.com:<pathto>/repo.git` using ssh) will work

Comment: As of 13th August 2021, this approach is no longer supported by github,so this will not work.

Comment: @Fewture It still works, just replace password with Github Token, how to generate a personal access token: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Instead, you can just do it in one step `git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/username/reponame.git`

Comment: Indeed in 2021 it woks with token, need to make sure the token has repo rights in its scope

Comment: Looks like adding origin like this will not work, please check this link for the updated solution : https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations

Comment: Does not work for me although I used a token with EVERY possible permission

Comment: Username and Password don't work anymore, instead, you have to use your [Personal access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), like so `git remote set-url origin https://PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/username/reponame.git`

Comment: or do the browser login flow by running `gh auth login`

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. 
Before that deleted all git credentials from credential manager and did not helped.

Comment: Update May 2023:
changing the remote url to https://username@github.com/path-to/repo.git solved this issue

Answer (score 175):

I ran into the same issue and I solved it by including my username and password in the repo url:

```
git clone https://myusername:mypassword@github.com/path_to/myRepo.git
```

Comment: This worked for me by added just my username: `https://myusername@github.com/path_to/myRepo.git`

Comment: this works but of course a lot of people would consider it a security problem; use with caution

Comment: This worked for me. I had used Git Bash previously for a different account and couldn't figure out how to change the account, so there ya go. Don't like it, but it works.

Comment: As a follow-up to my original comment, once you successfully push once, you can use the `git remote set-url origin url` command to change your origin URL to the same thing without the user name and password, and then it works fine.

Comment: I recommend using a credential helper rather than storing your password in plain text: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: Why are you talking about cloning?

Comment: Yes that problem often arrises when working with more than one Github account on the same maschine

Comment: As of 13th August 2021, this approach is no longer supported by github,so this will not work.

Comment: this worked. Generate a 'Personal access token' and use it as password.

Comment: username:password does not work, however just use username@github.com and it will prompt you to authenticate.

Answer (score 141):

If you use Git on **Windows**, try to clear your credentials:

1. Locate "credential manager" (should be in your Control Panel)
2. Remove all credentials related to GitHub

[image]

Comment: Nice - thanks for this successful hint! BTW, with following command you can navigate directly to the credential manager: "control.exe /name Microsoft.CredentialManager"

Comment: This worked, I had another account on github that caused the problem

Comment: You saved my time. I had the same issue after using sourcetree. I added multiple git accounts, which ruined Git configuration. After removing credentials, it worked like a charm.Thanks

Comment: I had remove all credentials from the it and then try to push it again on the repo and I am getting the same error! "Repo not found"

Answer (score 92):

I was getting the same error

```
ERROR: Repository not found.   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

and I had created the repository on Github and cloned it locally.

I was able to solve by opening .git/config and removing the `[remote "origin"]` section.

```
[remote "origin"]   
   url = git@github.com:alexagui/my_project.git  
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

then I ran the following (again)

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:alexagui/my_project.git  
git push -u origin master
```

and this time I was able to push to the repository.

Comment: Could you please explain how did you open .git/config and remove the [remote "origin"] section?

Comment: I came here looking for answers to a similar problem. I had created a new repository from IntelliJ IDEA, but got the same error message when I tried to do my initial push. Alex Aguilar's answer inspired me to go in the .git/config file and edit the repository URL so that it used my username with a capital first letter, which it initially did not do. It fixed my problem.

Comment: The `.git/` directory can be found on the project's root directory.

Comment: That also fixed the problem for me - I tried to switch user in the middle of a project and it opened a world of pain

Comment: why would that be necessary? I changed my username and now I'm facing all sorts of issues.

Comment: BTW, Thanks for saving the day

Comment: @DaviMoreira you can open and edit your .git/config via `sudo nano .git/config` or via `vim .git/config` . Both open an inline editor, for the first one you need your sudo password. I recommend googling some short cuts on how to save and exit either one.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to delete the `[remote "upstream"]` section. I had the error because I changed remote from one repo to another one with a different name....

Comment: For me I was adding remote by using https, and then solution is to remove it first, and then re-add remote origin but using git url

Comment: +10 on this - thanks!

Answer (score 66):

I got this error (but before was working). My problem was the missing ssh key binded with the Github account. You can check you current ssh keys with `ssh-add -l`.

If your key is missing, you can add it with

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_key
```

Comment: I changed my github account and therefore had to change my existing ssh key. Your fix did the trick, thanks!

Comment: I had to run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and then `ssh-add <key>` otherwise it didn't work

Comment: How to do that, is there a tutorial? I don't understand

Comment: If you added the key to .ssh/config, restart the ssh agent to pickup the new config. For MacOS I had to stop and start with `aunchctl stop com.openssh.ssh-agent` (replace accordingly)

Comment: from git hub documentation "ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519"
 worked for me.

Answer (score 66):

I faced this error when I was trying to push to a private repo that I had access to before. The problem was not whether the repo is private or public, the issue is that the Github API uses personal tokens instead of username and password for authentication and authorization now.

The following solved my problem:

1. remove the remote origin: `git remote remove origin`
2. Generate a personal token: you can find the instructions in [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-token).
3. Re-add the origin but with your username and the generated token:

`git remote add origin  https://USERNAME:GENERATED_TOKEN@github.com/username/reponame.git`

**N.B.**
If you encounter this issue a while after creating and using your token, make sure the token is not expired. If it is, regenerate it and make sure to repeat step 3 (mentioned above) for the repos that used the old token. Also, if you changed your token, redo step 3 for the repos that used the old token.

Comment: Incredible! This is the only thing that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This is the solution, not sure why its not been upvoted more.

Comment: If I'm loading an `ssh` key, shouldn't it work?

Comment: This worked for me as well, with a private repository.

Comment: Ace! This also solved my issue of commits showing as both my GitHub accounts stored in IntelliJ, now it just shows the one I've selected for the project 

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.  After a long time searching. Github recently started using the personal access codes so most of the answers are old.

Comment: Worked for me as well, was working with a private repository in an organization I owned. Not sure why it didnt work, but it has been a while since I auth'd so possibly auth expiration on previous token? Anyways thank you!

Comment: This works for me too, after trying all the previous answer. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

**I'm using Mac** and I struggled to find the solution. 
My remote address was right and as said, it was **a credentials problem**. 
Apparently, in the past I used another Git Account on my computer and the mac's Keychain remembered the credentials of the previous account, so I really wasn't authorised to push.

How to fix? 
Open **Keychain Access** on your mac, choose "All Items" category and search for git. 
**Delete** all results found.

Now go to the terminal and try to push again. The terminal will ask for username and password. Enter the new relevant credentials and that's it!

Hope it'll help someone. I struggled it for few hours.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you !!!!! I was banging my head against the wall already.

Comment: This really helped. Tried everything and just could not understand. Push, Pull CLone, works from IntelliJ but not from Terminal. After cleaning Keychain, it works like magic.

Comment: For macOS this was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Gal Shahar, you know you are the best. right?

Comment: What if I want to use multiple GitHub accounts simultaneously.

Comment: thank you so much brother, you saved my life, none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar problem.  The incorrect credentials were cached in OS X's key-chain.

Check out: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain

Comment: Same issue. I get `remote: Repository not found.` when accessing to private repo. It was because still connected to repo with old credentials (even with new ones in local git config). To fix 1) remove key from keychain. 2) do the command in the terminal again. 3) Should ask for username and password.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Nuked the credentials in keychain, got a new personal access token via Github GUI and am off and running, thanks.

Comment: @Antoine's answer is what happened to me. Unfortunately, I found this after I fixed the problem. In my case, I just turned on 2FA (Two Factor Authentication) (TFA). This broke my password. So, I cleared credentials (like people on this page said) but recloning a repo still failed with my password (I'm guessing due to 2FA). So, I created  Personal Access Token (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) to use in place of the password. I gave it repo access only since it's on the command line.

Answer (score 27):

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <remote url>
```

Comment: Worked for me. This issue started coming after git update.

Comment: This worked for me by switching the https url with the git@ one.

Answer (score 23):

`Github` removed use of `username` and `password`on August 13, 2021. Now uses `personal tokens` instead

To overcome that generate a `personal token` using  [create personal token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). And use the following snippets to achieve `push` and `clone` functionalities

### To Push

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://[USER]:[TOKEN]@github.com/[USER]/[REPO]
git push
```

### To Clone

```
git clone https://[USER]:[TOKEN]@github.com/[USER]/[REPO]
```

Comment: Wow, it saves me a lot of time.
THankssssss

Comment: This should be right/accepted answer, we can also add credentials in global config file

Comment: This literally woked and saved the time.

Answer (score 22):

`remote: Repository not found.` can be a frustratingly misleading error message from [github](/questions/tagged/github) when trying to push to an HTTPS remote where **you don't have write permissions**.

#### [Check your write permissions on the repository!](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-an-individual-s-access-to-an-organization-repository/)

Trying an SSH remote to the same repository shows a different response:

```
% git remote add ssh git@github.com:our-organisation/some-repository.git

% git fetch ssh
From github.com:our-organisation/some-repository
* [new branch]        MO_Adding_ECS_configs             -> ssh/MO_Adding_ECS_configs
* [new branch]        update_gems                       -> ssh/update_gems

% git push ssh     
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

"The correct access rights?"

Well *why didn't you say so?*

It's worth noting at this point that while the SSH failure mode in this scenario
is *slightly* better, I use HTTPS remotes over SSH because
[GitHub *recommend* HTTPS over SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended).

I understand that GitHub uses "Not Found" where it means "Forbidden" in some
circumstances to prevent inadvertently reveling the existence of a private
repository.

> Requests that require authentication will return `404 Not Found`, instead of
> `403 Forbidden`, in some places. This is to prevent the accidental leakage of
> private repositories to unauthorized users.

--[GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)

This is a fairly common practice around the web, indeed it is defined:

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find
> a current representation for the target resource or **is not willing to
> disclose that one exists.**

--[6.5.4. 404 Not Found, RFC 7231 HTTP/1.1 Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) (emphasis mine)

What makes no sense to me is when I am authenticated with GitHub using a
[credential helper](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)
*and* I have access to that repository (having successfully cloned and fetched
it) that GitHub would *choose* to hide its existence from me because of missing
write permissions.

Checking https://github.com/our-organisation/some-repository/ using a web
browser confirmed that **I didn't have write permissions to the repository**. Our
team's GitHub administrators were able to grant my team write access in a short
time and I was able to push the branch up.

Answer (score 17):

If your repo was working normally before, and suddenly this error pops up, most likely the reason would be that **your git is authenticated as some other user, that does not have access to the repository**. So, in order to push, all you need to do is, specify your correct username and password in your git command. So, a push command for a github repo would look like:

```
git push https://youruser:password@github.com/user/reponame.git
```

`username and password` needs to be url-escaped, so an **@** should be replaced by **%40**, and so on.

Comment: This worked for me first time. I created the problem initially by deleting the .gitconfig from C:/users/{username}

Comment: or `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` then `ssh-add ~/.ssh/<key_of_user>`

Answer (score 14):

That's what worked for me:

**1. The Remotes**

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<USER>/<REPO>.git
```

*If your SSH key is already in use on another github rep, you can generate a new one.*

**2. Generating a new SSH key**

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "web@github.com"
```

**3. Addition of the key at the SSH agent level**

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

**4. Add the new key to the Github repo.**

Answer (score 11):

One problem, that may be obvious to some that I don't see mentioned here, could be that you have access with ssh keys, but you are trying to connect your local repo to a remote via https.

If this is the case then the following commands should fix the issue for you:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/private-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/private-repo.git (push)
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:private-repo.git
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:private-repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:private-repo.git (push)
```

> Note that the above works assuming that:
>
> 1. your current remote is named `origin` and that you do already have a
>      generated ssh key connected with your github account
> 2. you already have an ssh key associated with your github account (and connected locally)
> 3. you have the correct permissions (read/write) set on github for this repo's settings.

Comment: This worked for me. But what was the breaking change? It was working fine just the other week and this was a repo I've had around for years.

Comment: @DylanNissley perhaps the security settings of the repo changed? I'm not sure, to be honest. :/

Answer (score 10):

Had similar issue. The root of the problem was that I followed some online tutorial about adding a **new repository** to Github.

Just go to Github, create a new repo, it will ask you to add a README, **don't add** it. Create it, and you'll get instructions on how to push.

It's similar to the next two lines:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/YOUR_USER/your-repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 10):

If you belong to a group in Github check that you have Write Access.

Comment: How exactly does one do that? It would be more complete if you could add such info.

Comment: just got to your git repository and click on any file and try to edit it.If you dont have write access then you will shown some error like "you are trying to edit a file ...."

Comment: A quick way to check is to click `Create new file`. If you get a message saying "You’re creating a file in a project you don’t have write access to", then you don't have write access.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue on a MAC trying to pull from a private repo i was previously connected to.

I solved it by including my username in the repo url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE>@github.com/<YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE>/<REPO>.git
```

Then i was able to pull from the repo.

For a new repo you want to clone:

```
git clone https://<YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE>@github.com/<YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE>/<REPO>.git
```

It will prompt you to enter your password to that account, you're good to go afterwards.

Comment: I am on a Mac, I'm using a private repo that I've been able to pull from. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for checking in. The problem was that I had read but not write access to the repo.

Answer (score 8):

This Solved my problem.

```
   git pull https://myusername:mypassword@github.com/path_to/myRepo.git
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to solve my issue

```
#check current github account
ssh -T git@github.com

#ensure the correct ssh key used with github
ssh-agent -s
ssh-add ~/.ssh/YOUR-GITHUB-KEY

#re-add the origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR-USER/YOUR-REPO.GIT
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem (on Linux), I merely had to run this:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Answer (score 7):

**The Problem**: Github is not familiar with your repository from some reason.

**The Error:** prompted in git cli like the following:

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository
>   ‘https://github.com/MyOrganization/projectName.git/’ not found

**The Solution :** 2 Options

1. **Github might not familiar with your credentials:** - The first Option is to clone the project with the right credentials `user:password` in case you forgot this Or generate ssh token and adjust this key in your Github. aka `git push https://<userName>:<password>@github.com/Company/repositoryName.git`
2. **Repo Permissions Issue with some users** - In my Use case, I solved this issue when **I realized I don't have the right collaborator permissions on Github** in my private repo. Users could clone the project but not perform any actions on origin. In order to solve this:

> Go to Repository on Github -> Settings -> Collaborators & Teams -> Add
>   Member/Maintainer your users -> Now they got the permission to commit
>   and push

Answer (score 6):

You need to check your SSH access as the following:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

this issue was because i don't add the person response on SSH in repository, read more about SSH [link-1](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found), [link-2](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

Comment: This showed up an issue with multiple keys and a config file that wasn't working. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

If you clone from github using `https` but you are using `ssh` to push, you can also get this error.

To correct this, open `.git/config` and replace:

`url = https://github.com/company/project.git`

With

`url = git@github.com:company/project.git`

And you should be able to push with no warning...

Answer (score 6):

I solved that issue by re-authentifacating with Github.

If you have Github CLI, you can type `gh auth login`

Comment: I had issues writing to an organization repo. By default you only get read access to org repos. The gh cli makes it easy to get write access too by running `gh auth login --scopes write:org`

Answer (score 5):

Have experienced the same problem. Everything was working fine for years and then suddenly this error.

The problem turns out was that I added a deploy key for another repo to my SSH agent before my user's github SSH key (which I always used to access the repo in question). SSH agent tried the deploy key for another repo first, and GitHub for some totally unexplainable reason was saying

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
```

Once I've removed the deploy key from SSH agent, everything was back to normal.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, specifically by running `ssh-add -D`. This is on macOS.

Answer (score 5):

The following solved the problem for me.

First I used this command to figure what was the github account used:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

This gave me an answer like this:

```
Hi <github_account_name>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. I just had to give the access to fix the problem.
```

Then I understood that the Github user described in the answer (github_account_name) wasn't authorized on the Github repository I was trying to pull.

Comment: What to do if i get this error: `The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Try the following:

1. Modifying the Keychain Access in Mac for git credentials solved the problem for me. 
2. Resetting origin url

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:account-name/repo-name.git
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue with one of my Github Repository.

### Way around:

> Used `SSH` instead of `HTTPS` and then `push/pull` started working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I can explain how i get into the similar situation, and then will list steps that i have taken to solve this issue.

I am using
Windows 10,
git: git version 2.27.0.windows.1.

I had already setup the git and was doing git push activities. Windows Credential Manager stores the username and password so you don't have to enter username and password every git remote activities.

The encounter this problem, when i added another github account and used --local git settings. After few days, I encounter the Repository not found problem, upon investigation i found:

1. Even if you remove the git details from Windows Credential Manager, it will save again the username, email details you enter.

So, if you are using two git accounts, you need to use (git bash as an administrator)

```
git config --edit --system
```

and remove the

```
helper = manager
```

line so that it is no longer registered as a credential helper. But it will ask you login details every time you do any remote activities.

[How do I disable Git Credential Manager for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-do-i-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows).

To check remote origin, user details

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use the SSH remote url instead of the HTTPS

Answer (score 4):

Changing the content of the .git/config file helps as Alex said above. I experienced the same problem and I think it was because I changed my Github username. The local files could not be updated with the changes. So perhaps anytime you change your username you might consider running

`git remote add origin your_ssh_link_from_github`

I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 4):

If anybody faced the issue at github.com check if you have accepted an invitation after repo owner allowed commits to you. Until you accept invitation repo will be invisible for you. So you'll get `ERROR: Repository not found.`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem.

Comment: Same thing here, I would expect the error message to be something like "You don't have permission to write" or something like that. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Software by Linus is not a software that does expected things.

Answer (score 4):

Normally it happens because the project is private and you have not rights to write it. I had the same "problem" a few times, and it was for that reason.
If the project it is yours, just create a private and a public key following this link: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent and add them to the "SSH and Key" section on gitHub, then you will be able to push to the repo. In the other hand if the project it is not your, ask the owner to give you the rights for it.

Answer (score 4):

Before following this, make sure you've write permission to the repo. If you're still getting the error, do the following :

1. Generate a personal access token from your account from Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access tokens. Keep the token safe somewhere.
2. Go to your repository and run the following:

   `git remote rm origin`
3. Then add a new origin along with your username:

   `git remote add origin https://USERNAME@github.com/REPOSITORY_LINK.git`
4. Now when you push the code, a prompt will show up asking for your password or personal access token. Paste the token that we generated in the first step in the field, and we're done.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was this:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://USERNAME@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

Similar to Emi-C's answer but without passwords.

Comment: Or you can just edit the URL in .git/config under `[remote "origin"]`

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure you already have SSH access to this repository.

Do

```
git clone https://myusername@github.com/path_to/myRepo.git
```

Answer (score 4):

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

It was my own repo - there should be enough access. For other repos I was able to pull & push with no problem. It was solved by starting `ssh-agent` over again. I use macos.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was because of that I added the same SSH key in another GitHub account also. Steps to check and fix

1. Check it: `ssh -T git@github.com`. If it shows the correct username then the issue is different. If it is another account then do step 2.
2. Simply go to another account and delete ssh keys from there.
3. Use different keys for different accounts. Github really mix up them.

Answer (score 3):

Had this same issue when working on a **MacBook Pro**.

When I try to clone or push to a repository, I get the error below:

```
git clone https://github.com/mytech/mytech_frontend.git

Cloning into 'mytech_frontend'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mytech/mytech_frontend.git/' not found
```

This often happens if the computer already has github.com credentials configured in the CLI for another user.

**Here's how I solved it**:

**For Git Clone**

First, be sure you have access to the repository either as:

- a member of the organization in which the repository resides OR
- a collaborator of the repository

Next, clone the repository using:

```
git clone https://github.com/path_to/my-repo.git
```

if you have an existing GitHub account on the computer/terminal, when you try to clone from a repository with another GitHub account you will encounter the same error, so you need to modify your git clone command to:

```
git clone https://my-username:'personal-access-token'@github.com/path_to/my-repo.git
```

Example:

```
git clone https://promisepreston:'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'@github.com/promisepreston/my-writings.git
```

**For Git Push**

List the existing repo remote location:

```
git remote -v
```

Output:

```
origin  https://github.com/my-username/my-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/my-username/my-repo.git (push)
```

Remove the existing remote location:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Add the repo remote location again using this pattern:

```
git remote add origin https://my-username:'personal-access-token'@github.com/path_to/my-repo.git
```

Example:

```
git remote add origin https://promisepreston:'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'@github.com/promisepreston/my-writings.git
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My issue was misunderstanding that I had to first create the empty repo on github before pushing to it. Doh! Including this here for anyone else who doesn't realize.

Answer (score 2):

go to your project folder then search for the .git folder, then open the config file with notepad and check if there is your link to the github repo under: [remote "origin"], if it is different then the repo in your github then just edit it, or open a new repo with the name in the in config file

Answer (score 2):

If you use private repository check you connection user, it must have permission for use repository.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and realized I was using a different account from the one whose repo it was. Logging in as the original user resolved the issue.

Comment: In my case I had set up 2 accounts and added entries in .ssh/config for alias work and personal and forgotten about it .So; changing the origin part in .git/config of the project directory so that I had work instead of 'github.com' solved the issue.Problem was that while cloning I had used git@github.com:blahblah and not git@work:blahblah.

Answer (score 1):

My solution may be useful to some of you.

I got the same error after updating my macbook's OS to Yosemite. My problem got fixed by recreating my ssh key. You can do this by following step 2 of this page: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Answer (score 1):

So for me, my password had a ` (tick) in it and PhpStorm was removing the character before sending the git push:

Lets say for this example my password is ``` _pa``ssword_ ```

Phpstorm would output the following:

`https://_username_:_password_@github.com/_username_/repo.git`

instead of

``` https://_username_:_pa``ssword_@github.com/_username_/repo.git ```

Changed password to something not using the ` character. WORKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to kill credential-helper processes (were multiple) and it solved the issue after providing credentials once again.

`killall git-credential-cache--daemon`

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem and tried many ways but at last, I have got to know that I don't have sufficient permissions to push or pull on this repo and one more way to check if you are having the permissions or not is you were not able to see settings option in that repo and if you were having permissions then you will be able to see settings option

Thanks! this is what I observed

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Step 1:**

Copy the link from the HTTPS

**Step 2:**

in the local repository do

```
git remote rm origin
```

**Step 3**:

replace github.com with username.password@github.com in the copied url

**Step 4:**

```
git remote add origin url
```

Answer (score 1):

I (and many others) have had this problem since may 2021.
Something seems to have changed in actions/checkout@v2 (GitHub issue: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/254)

I resolved it by changing the way the runner authenticates to the repo by using this step.

```
- name: Bump version
    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
    run: |
      npm run release
      git remote rm origin
      git remote add origin https://${{github.actor}}:${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}@github.com/project/repo.git
      git remote -v # for debug only 
      git show-ref # for debug only 
      git push --follow-tags origin HEAD:master
```

All you need to do is to change the repo url. Username and password will be replaced at runtime by the GitHub runner. This works for both `actions/checkout@v1` and `actions/checkout@v2` (haven't tested others).

Also many snippets you find online already come with a permission restriction that will prevent you from pushing back to the repo

```
permissions:
   packages: write
   contents: read
```

Make sure you remove this or grant your action contents:write permission if you need to push a tag or commit release notes and package bumps.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I created a personal developer token without permissions

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by git using the wrong ssh private key.
I was given access to the repository under a specific github user account I am using for school. My default ssh private key was unfortunately linked to a different github account.

If you do `ssh -T git@github.com` ssh will automatically use your `id_rsa` private key to connect to github.

Using `ssh -i ~/.ssh/<some-key> -T git@github.com` should result in github greeting you with the account you linked to that key.

So what happened in my case was that git was using my default ssh private key which was linked to the wrong github account which didn't have access to the private repository I was trying to access.

To solve this I told git to use the correct ssh command in the local git config for my repo using the command: `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/<correct private key here>"`

Viewing the git configuration `git config -l` should show that the line was properly added.

Comment: Definitely the most understandable answer for ssh noobs like me. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specific to **IntelliJ** products such as **IDEA  / WebStorm / PHPStorm** when using **organizations**.

> I had this problem with WebStorm when trying to push to a repository that was part of
> an organization, meanwhile pushing to a repository within my normal
> private account worked.
>
> Also, pushing to my organizational repository with IntelliJ IDEA worked

So I thought this could only be something related to a setting that differs between both IDEs, and I found out that I had the checkbox "Use credential helper" enabled in WebStorm, and disabled in IDEA.

[image]

**Disabling the credential helper made it working!!**

Comment: I'm facing this issue again, but now with Git Bash, while IntelliJ works

Answer (score 1):

If you had everything automated by vscode before and now it's no longer working, Try signing out of your connected github account on vscode and signing back in to the right github account that has access to that repository.

Here is where you sign out and sign back in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you include your username and the repo name we can reasonably help you, at the moment we have no reason to think the repo does actually exist.

Additionally, if the repo is private and you don't have access to it, github returns "Does not exist" to avoid disclosing the existance of private repos.

EDIT: If you're not able to clone it because it's saying it doesn't exist and it's private, it's because you're not sending authentication. Ensure that your public key is added to your keyring, or use HTTP basic auth for the time being.

Comment: He stated that it's private, so giving the repo name won't help much.

Comment: my approach will certainly verify that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error after updating my ubuntu to next version

I just deleted my sshkey on github account and then re added an sshkey to that account.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error coz I change my github user name, then I do this:

```
git remote -v
```

then:

```
git remote set-url newname newurl 
git push -u origin master
```

this time I was able to push to the repository.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to try this.
What values do I put in newname, newurl?
Does this change my user name on the repository at github.com?

Comment: fixed with alex aguilar's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

first Create a new repository on the command line, name like  Ademo.git

Create a new repository on the command line

touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/your_name/Ademo.git
git push -u origin master

Push an existing repository from the command line

git remote add origin https://github.com/your_name/Ademo.git
git push -u origin master

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a Fork

If don't have write access to that repository, you don't need it. Create a fork by following [**these instructions**](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) -- it's your own clone of the repository which you can modify freely.

After creating the fork, you can then clone that repo to your computer.

```
git clone git@github.com:<your-git-handle>/<repository>.git
// It will be cloned to your machine where you run the command 
// under a <repository> folder that it will create.
```

Checkout a new branch and make changes.

```
git checkout -b my-new-feature
```

To submit your changes to the original repository, you'll need to make sure that they're pushed

```
/* make changes */
git commit -am "New Feature: Made a new feature!"
git push origin my-new-feature
```

To get these changes into the original repository that you forked from, you can submit a Pull Requests by following [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/). A Pull Request basically, you request that the user with write access to a repository pull down the changes you've made. Think of it like "I request that you pull my changes into your repo."

---

**Note**: Your fork will not stay up-to-date with all of the changes going on in the original repository, though. You'll have to pull down those changes periodically -- but this is easy.

After creating the fork, you can link to repo that you've forked from so that you can pull in it's changes and keep stay current.

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:<git-user-handle>/<repository>.git
```

Once you've done that, keeping in sync with the changes made on the original repo is quite easy.

```
git checkout master         // checkout your local master
git pull upstream master    // fetch changes from the master branch of the repo you forked from.. which is linked to your fork under the alias "upstream" (common naming convention)
git push origin master      // push the pulled changes onto your local master
git checkout -b new-branch  // create a new branch and start making changes
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen because GitHub itself is down. Make sure to check status.github.com to see if the problem might lie on their side.

On October 22nd 2018 you couldn't push to GitHub for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I solved prefixing my gitlab username to the gitlab.com url, so like this:
before: 
https://gitlab.com/my_gitlab_user/myrepo.git 
and after:
https://my_gitlab_user@gitlab.com/my_gitlab_user/myrepo.git
In this case will ask for the credentials again and it's done!

Answer (score 0):

My code snippet:

```
environment {
    ...
    ...
    git_repo = 'my-repo'
}

stage ('Update Helm Chart') {
    steps {
        echo 'Updating values.xml file with latest Docker image tag'

        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '6bgg7dd45-c65f13-4275-a96ddehdv67gdr', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USER', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASS')]) {
            sh '''
                git checkout ${git_branch}
                ...
                ...
                git remote set-url origin "http://${GIT_USER}:${GIT_PASS}@git.example.com/scm/${git_repo}.git"
                git push origin ${git_branch}
            '''
        }
    }
}
```

My Git user name was `deploy.user@example.com` so i had to first [URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) `@` to `%40`. After URL encoding, my user name became `deploy.user%40example.com`.

However, i was still getting the following error:

```
fatal: repository 'http://****:****@git.example.com/scm/my-repo.git/' not found
```

After some trial and error, i found that if i don't use variable for user name and instead hard-code it, it works.

```
git remote set-url origin "http://deploy.user%40example.com:${GIT_PASS}@git.example.com/scm/${git_repo}.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using *Android Studio*, I was unable to push commits because of the auth error.

My working temporary solution was to use the [GitHub desktop app](https://desktop.github.com) to push my commits and it works fine.

Comment: The terminal should behave more or less the same apart from visuals. So I doubt that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all options, but nothing seemed to work. Further research revealed the following:

1. [Here](https://www.javaprogramto.com/2021/11/git-remote-repository-not-found.html) is a comprehensive approach to solving the problem.
2. When you get to **5. Fix 4**, note that VS code will ask for authentication.

If you enter your password and still get an authentication error, do the following.

1. Head over to your GitHub menu do *Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access tokens -> Generate new token*. And ensure the boxes are checked according to the picture below. Generate an access token and save it somewhere accessible. [image]
2. Use the generated token instead of the password.
3. Then continue to step **[6. Fix 5](https://www.javaprogramto.com/2021/11/git-remote-repository-not-found.html)**

These steps should fix the problem afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have 2 TWO(or more) GitHub accounts:**

you will run into issue:

`"key already in use"` for the same computer

**Solution:**

1. create a new key per each `organization/account/email`

   `$ sudo ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "other@email.com"`
2. add identity

   `$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/"whatever key you created"`

make sure to add all the `"identities"` or `ssh keys` which tells git which keys to try to use when authenticating with `GitHub` under all organizations.

Answer (score 0):

This **SOLVED** the problem:

1. Check your link has correct spelling, you can copy on Github
   [image]
2. If you're correct all the spelling, maybe your **Credential Remote** is the issue. Go to Control panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials. Find `git:https://github.com` and click **Remove**.
   [image]

Make sure you come to `git:https://github.com` not the other *..github.com
[image]

Then, now you can do git clone or push or any with your repo. It worked for me!

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Even with so many answers there's another potential issue and solution:

In my case i'm using a devContainer and have logged in to VS Code with Github. However this is not sufficient. You need to use a personal access token and follow this specific part about the github CLI

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git#github-cli

log in with personal token and NOT with browser.

You can create the token through settings of your own account -> developer settings -> personal access token -> finegrained

Paste that in the CLI. Reopen the devContainer and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

There's something that I find that is often missing from documentation, which is the fact that in order to add a remote repo, the repo seems to need to exist first.

When I start a new project, and want to push it directly to a new repo on Github, I do this:

1. `git init` -> This initialises Git. Git will now track changes.
2. `gh repo create <REPO_NAME>` -> This creates the repo on your Github account.  If you don't have the Github CLI, you may need to create the repo manually
3. `git remote add origin git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPO_NAME>.git` -> this connects your local repo with the one on Github.  If you're using HTTPS and not SSH, you may need to use the HTTPS url: `https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO_NAME>.git`
4. `git push -u origin main` -> this pushes the tracked, committed changes to the Github repo.

Answer (score -1):

Also be sure to check whether you have desktop client installed. I double checked everything, my permission, SSH, but turns out my repo listed in the client was overriding the one I was inputting via terminal.

Answer (score -1):

you have to generate ssh key and add it in your github account in settings
go to your project where you clone inside that run these command.-

1-ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "rajankumar148@gmail.com"

after the command you will get some options path and name can be leave empty and you can put password.

2-eval $(ssh-agent -s) .

3-ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

after this command you have to put same password that you created in 1st command

and after that you can check your default home directory or whatever directory it is showing on the terminal .pub file open and copy the key and past in github settings new ssh

Answer (score -1):

Using **Ubuntu**, I always have to add remote using SSH instead of HTTPS

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git
```

instead of

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/project.git
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, none of these replies were useful.
I had just forgotten to create the repo on the remote (on github.com). So I created my repo online, using the same name, and then re-done

So, here is the whole story:

```
git init ...
git add ...
git commit ...
git remote add origin git@github.com:<myName>/<myRepo>.git
git push -u origin main

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

--> Here you need to add your repo on github.com with the same "myRepo" name

```
git push -u origin main
```