# Determine a collaborator's permissions (to an organization repos) via the api?

Tags: api, github

In a repos that belongs to an organization (as opposed to an individual), collaborators are members of "teams", and teams can have three different kinds of permissions:

- Pull Only
- Push & Pull
- Push, Pull, & Administrative

I can see a list of collaborators on a repos like this:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators
```

...but it does not tell me what type of permissions a collaborator has.

In this particular case, I am one of the collaborators; I do not own the repository.

Is there a way to programmatically determine the type of collaborator permission I have?

Comment: In fact it _does_ return permissions [at least under some conditions](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#list-collaborators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update June 2017: You now have **[nested teams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44530200/6309)**.
However, the [`orgs/teams` API](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#list-user-teams) mentions:

> The REST API v3 does not yet fully support nested teams.
>   For example, the endpoints for [List team members](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#list-team-members) and [List team repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#list-team-repos) do not return results inherited from a nested team's structure.

Warning: since January 2020, The Team APIs will be moving from a top-level path under `/teams/:team_id` to a scoped path under the organization that owns the team with a path like `/organizations/:org_id/team/:team_id`.
See "[**Moving the teams API**](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-01-21-moving-the-team-api-endpoints/)" by **[Dirkjan Bussink](https://github.com/dbussink)**

---

Original answer 2016

The one query which should include your permission is mentioned in "[List User Teams](http://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#list-user-teams)"

```
GET /user/teams
```

> List all of the teams across all of the organizations to which the authenticated user belongs. This method requires user or repo [scope](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) when authenticating via [OAuth](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/).

The answer looks like:

```
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999

[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/teams/1",
    "name": "Owners",
    "id": 1,
    "permission": "admin",                     <============
    "members_count": 3,
    "repos_count": 10,
    "organization": {
      "login": "github",
      "id": 1,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif"
    }
  }
]
```

You need to filter that result in order to [match the team with the right repo](http://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#list-team-repos), and you should get back the permission level associated to that repo that way.

Comment: Note that `/user/teams` assumes that the user looking for this information is the same as the user being checked for permissions.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to check whether you have push access to a GitHub repo, you can use the [`repo` endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get):

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo`

If your request includes your authorization information (either including your account credentials or an OAuth access token), the `permissions` field will give you the information you're looking for:

`{
    'admin': False, 
    'push': False, 
    'pull': True
}`

Comment: More focused on an individual for a particular repo, as opposed to my answer (reading admin right for an all team). Interesting. +1