# GitHub API How to check if user has write access to a repository

Tags: github-api

I currently have a bot which automates a few GitHub operations, like merging pull requests, notifying staff on Slack when a PR is opened, that kind of thing (it's a custom flavored Hubot instance)

When staff give him the command to merge a pull request, he firstly checks to see if they belong to a team which has write access to that repository. It works, but the code isn't great.

First he gets all teams on the organization, loops through them, gets all users assigned to that team, if he finds the user issuing the merge command, he then checks to see if that team has write access. If not does, authentication is good.

Is this the best way to go about it? I feel like it could be much simpler.

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE: there is now a GitHub API endpoint for this:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/collaborators#check-if-a-user-is-a-repository-collaborator

---

OLD ANSWER: There isn't a much simpler way to do this currently (but I agree that it would be great if there was a more elegant way to get this information). You could perhaps reduce the number of requests by fetching [the user's teams](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#list-user-teams) and [the list of teams which have access to the repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-teams) (and not all teams in the organizations). The intersection of these two lists should allow you to answer the question, I think.

(Also, in your solution, note that you not only have to check that the user is a member of a push-access team -- you also need to check that this push-access team [has access to the repository in question](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#get-team-repo). The user could have been a member of a push-access team which doesn't have access to the repository in question, and a member of a pull-access team which does have access to the repository in question.)

Comment: @lukerollins I just updated the answer with a link to a new endpoint which allows you to do this: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#review-a-users-permission-level

Answer (score 1):

My company uses Github enterprise.

This [API Docs link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#get) helped

> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators/:username

If user has access you would get a response similar to

> Status: 204 No Content
>
> X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
>
> X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999

Comment: As noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733221/determine-a-collaborators-permissions-to-an-organization-repos-via-the-api this is not enough to distinguish access modes, in case some teams are given pull access and others greater access. For some applications it may not matter.

Comment: The workaround is to enumerate all `/repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators`, searching for a match with the given user and then checking `permissions`, but this is inefficient especially since paging might force you to make multiple requests. I contacted GitHub and a representative agreed that they might consider an API dedicated to this purpose.