# Why can I not push to a github repo?

Tags: git, github

I was added as a member to a private repo. I visited the repo page and copied the git repo address: https://github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git

I then entered the following into the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git
```

I edited some files and created a new local branch:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

I then added the changes, and committed them:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'Commit message here'
```

Next, I tried to push the changes to the repo in order to create a new remote branch:

```
git push -u origin new_branch
```

I also tried:

```
git push origin new_branch
```

Both failed to push the changes and displayed the following error message:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git/' not found
```

I found this page on Github(https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/) which addresses the error message I am seeing, but the repo is spelled correctly, I am a member of the team that has access to it(I cloned it in the first place), and I am not using SSH, so none of those apply to me.

Any ideas why I am not able to create a remote Github branch based on my local branch?

Comment: found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10235016/2723675) it seems like if you don't have write permissions when trying to push it returns the same `Error: Repository Not Found` message .

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can personally check if I have read-write access or do I need to ask the admin?

Comment: If you browse to the repo (in github's web gui), select a file, and click the edit link (shaped like a pencil) and try to "save" (actually I think it commits and offers to let you create a pull request) the changes. You should find out quickly if you have write permissions.

Comment: One of the options for "saving" is `Create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request.`, this may fit in better than just making a random change to someone's private repo.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235016/2723675).

It seems like if you don't have write permissions when trying to push, GitHub returns the same `Error: Repository Not Found message`.

Comment: This is exactly what was wrong! Thanks for all your help!