# How do I disable Git Credential Manager for Windows?

Tags: git, bash

I notice that in the latest version of Git, the default is now to popup a "Git Credential Manager for Windows" dialog instead of prompting me for me password at the Bash prompt every time.

I really hate this behaviour. How can I just disable it and go back to entering the password at the Bash shell every time?

By the way, I don't want Git caching my credentials *in any way*, whether through Windows credentials or some internal daemon. I want to disable *all credential caching*.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

OK, I discovered that you need to either *avoid* checking the "Git Credential Manager" checkbox during the Git for Windows installer, or (after installation) run the Bash shell as *Administrator* and use `git config --edit --system` to remove the `helper = manager` line so that it is no longer registered as a credential helper.

For bonus points, use `git config --edit --global` and insert:

```
[core]
    askpass =
```

To disable the OpenSSH credentials popup too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. For me, this was the first time to use the editor. If you want to save changes, hit the escape key and type :wq and hit enter (write/save and quit).

Comment: Many thanks! The credential manager got confused with my work's proxy server and it made working with Sourcetree a nightmare. Disabling it fixed the problem immediately.

Comment: and if :wq doesn't work like my case use ctrl+z for abort and quit but these will probably make multiple backup file to work with later

Comment: Or knock it out with `git config --system --unset credential.helper`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627269/jenkins-using-git-askpass-to-set-credentials/42636309?noredirect=1#comment76361367_42636309

Comment: Using "Git for Windows (64 bit)", the system config file is at  %ProgramFiles%\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig and the global config file is at %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig

Comment: I did uncheck it during install. The stupid thing still started popping up, even though I can't see anything in the config settings that would make it do so. But this fixes it. Thanks! You can also just set it to the empty string directly from the command line: `git config --global core.askpass ''`. @BenButzer In my experience, things keep putting it back. Better to override it to empty in your global config where other tools will (hopefully) not mess with it.

Comment: For those using SourceTree make sure that the "system" version of GIT is being used, not the embedded one. `Tools -> Options -> Git`.

Comment: The edit commands appear to be the same as "vi". See this for vi command keys: http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/basic/node168.html

Comment: Adding to the chain of woe-resolution. Unsetting `credential.helper` doesn't (no longer?) works. You need to do the following in admin session: `git config --global credential.helper '' ; git config --global core.askpass ''` ; and for good measure, do the same without `--global` in your local dirs in case they were set there too

Comment: @BenBesuijen "the editor" is called "vim"

Comment: @cowlinator My system file was in "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig". At least that is what `git config --edit --system` opens anyway. I don't seem to have a gitconfig in %ProgramFiles%\Git\mingw64\etc

Comment: @Caltor , yes, me too. It seems to have been changed sometime in the last 8 years.

Answer (score 37):

I was able to uninstall the Git Credential Manager for Windows using the uninstall option:

```
git-credential-manager.exe uninstall
```

Run this command in `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`

As of git-credential-manager version 2.2.2 (installed with git version 2.41.0.windows.3), this command has been replaced with `git-credential-manager unconfigure` [Edit thanks to @wrapperapps]

Comment: This just stalls and after I press ctrl-c, spits out this usage: `git credential [fill|approve|reject]`

Comment: @ScottN you're running `git-credential.exe` but you need to run `git-credential-manager.exe`.

Comment: as of git-credential-manager version 2.2.2 (installed with git version 2.41.0.windows.3), this command has been replaced with `git-credential-manager unconfigure`

Answer (score 20):

Another option I had to use with VSTS:

`git config --global credential.modalprompt false`

Comment: Thanks! I found it very useful when using ssh to connect remotely to my production server: I couldn't do a `git pull` because of the WCM shelling out. With this option I enjoy both worlds: WCM when connected physically with the server (or with Remote Desktop), and being able of pulling from a ssh client.

Answer (score 13):

It didn't work for me:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
git-credential-manager.exe uninstall

Looking for Git installation(s)...
  C:\Program Files\Git

Updated your /etc/gitconfig [git config --system]
Updated your ~/.gitconfig [git config --global]

Removing from 'C:\Program Files\Git'.
  removal failed. U_U

Press any key to continue...
```

But with the `--force` flag it worked:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
git credential-manager uninstall --force
08:21:42.537616 exec_cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
e
08:21:42.538616 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-credential-manager uninstall --force
08:21:42.538616 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager uninstall --force

Looking for Git installation(s)...
  C:\Program Files\Git

Updated your /etc/gitconfig [git config --system]
Updated your ~/.gitconfig [git config --global]


Success! Git Credential Manager for Windows was removed! ^_^

Press any key to continue...
```

I could see that trace after I run:

```
set git_trace=1
```

Also I added the Git username:

```
git config --global credential.username myGitUsername
```

Then:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

In the end I put in this command:

```
git config --global credential.modalPrompt false
```

I check if the SSH agent is running

- open a Bash window to run this command

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Then in the computer users/yourName folder where .ssh is, add a connection (still in Bash):

```
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```

or

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa (if you are not in that folder)
```

I checked all the settings that I add above:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
git config --list
09:41:28.915183 exec_cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-cor
e
09:41:28.917182 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --list
09:41:28.918181 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PAGER_IN_USE; LESS=FRX LV=-c less
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
credential.modalprompt=false
credential.username=myGitUsername
```

And when I did `git push` again I had to add username and password only for the first time.

```
git push
Please enter your GitHub credentials for https://myGithubUsername@github.com/
username: myGithubUsername
password: *************
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 316 bytes | 316.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
```

Since then using `git push`, I don't have the message to enter my Git credentials any more.

```
D:\projects\react-redux\myProject (master -> origin) (budget@1.0.0)
λ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 314 bytes | 314.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/myGitUsername/myProject.git
   8d38b18..f442d74  master -> master
```

After these settings I received an email too with the message:

```
A personal access token (git: https://myGitHubUsername@github.com/
on LAP0110 at 25-Jun-2018 09:22) with gist and repo scopes was recently added
to your account. Visit https://github.com/settings/tokens for more information.
```

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to use the credential manager for normal use, but I have scripts where I obviously do not want any prompts whatsoever from `git.exe`. This is how I invoke Git from my scripts:

```
set GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0
git -c core.askpass= -c credential.helper= <command> ...
```

This way, the script always sees the "correct" no-prompt setting without having to adapt any configuration.

(Git for Windows 2.13.3)

---

A variation I found that might also come in handy is to set:

```
set GCM_INTERACTIVE=never
# Or: git config --global credential.interactive never

set GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0
git.exe -c core.askpass= -c credential.helper=manager <command> ...
```

But note that `git.exe -c credential.interactive=never <command> ...`
does *not* work (it seems that the `-c` thing isn't routed through to Git Credential Manager for Windows or whatever).

That way, you *can* use the GCMfW, but it will never prompt you; it will just lookup the credentials, which can be very helpful in non-interactive environs.

Answer (score 9):

If you notice the credential manager UI popping up when you use a JetBrains IDE (such as [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm), [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm), [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), [Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#Rider), [RubyMine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs), [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio), or Goland), do this:

1. In your IDE, go to menu *File* → *Settings* → *Version Control* → *Git*.
2. Disable **Use credential helper**:

   [image: Disable "Use credential helper"]
3. Don't forget to press <kbd>Save</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core                                                                       
git credential-manager uninstall --force
```

This works on Windows systems. I tested it, and it worked for me.

Comment: worked for me before, but is no longer working for me on win10 with `git version 2.42.0.windows.2`. the command returns `Required command was not provided. Unrecognized command or argument 'uninstall'. Unrecognized command or argument '--force'.` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-do-i-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows/37185202#37185202) from @Jez is working for me now

Answer (score 7):

For problems where the tips in previous answers did not solve it:

I use

```sh
git credential-manager remove -force
```

Answer (score 7):

We *struggled* with this issue. While we tried to clone code from a Git repository, without prompting (asking) for a Git username  and password, it started cloning the code and finally failed due to authentication failed. Even credentials are not set and first time Git clone used.

Resolution: Run the command and it’s perfectly working.

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: For me, the command needed to be `git config --global --unset credential.helper`: I replaced --system by --global and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I had had that problem, and I've only removed the **git-credential-manager.exe** file from:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the problem is **Sourcetree**.

1. Go to *Tools* → *Options*
2. Uncheck "Check default remotes for updates every [10] minutes"
3. Restart Sourcetree!

Comment: Hi @hatonooh. Thanks for the hint, this helped me find the correct solution for me, but was not yours.
In Tools / Options : Authentication I removed my account. The next time I pulled my repo I had a prompt for password, which recreated this account.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the dialog, use `git config --global credential.modalPrompt false`

That'll drive the queries to the console.

Answer (score 2):

In case you **do not want to remove or uninstall** the credentials manager: see https://serverfault.com/questions/544156/git-clone-fail-instead-of-prompting-for-credentials/1054253#answer-1054253 for the solution that worked for me.

Explanations, etc. in that page (linked to prevent duplicate content in the same website family).

---

**TL;DR**: this now sits on top of my automated `bash` scripts:

```sh
# https://serverfault.com/questions/544156/git-clone-fail-instead-of-prompting-for-credentials
export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0
# next env var doesn't help...
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -oBatchMode=yes'
# these should shut up git asking, but only partly: the X-windows-like dialog doesn't pop up no more, but ...
export GIT_ASKPASS=echo
export SSH_ASKPASS=echo
# We needed to find *THIS* to shut up the bloody git-for-windows credential manager: 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-do-i-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows#answer-45513654
export GCM_INTERACTIVE=never
```

---

The *final* nail in the coffin of that credentials manager was the unique bit (`GCM_INTERACTIVE`) in Martin Ba's answer above: [How do I disable Git Credential Manager for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-do-i-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows#answer-45513654)

Answer (score 1):

> and if :wq doesn't work like my case use ctrl+z for abort and quit but these will probably make multiple backup file to work with later – Adeem Jan 19 at 9:14

Also be sure to run Git as Administrator! Otherwise the file won't be saved (in my case).

Answer (score 1):

I struck the same issue on [Ubuntu 18.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Cosmic Cuttlefish), unable to remove using any normal means.
I used `git config --global --unset credential.helper`, and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete the Credential Manager.

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the "user" folder, c://user,, look at the ".gitconfig" file, and then remove the HTTP and proxy line.

Answer (score 1):

I had another problem to set git not prompt for any password, I learned another command line trick one can use for this purpose.

In case you want a temporary solution for the terminal session you work on, this might come in handy:

`git -c credential.helper= <rest of the commands>`

Comment: works like a charm to avoid run process get stuck, indeed as a workaround

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio Code: Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Configuration* → *GitHub* → *gitAuthentication: false*. Change the repository's protocol from *https://* to *git://* and use public key authentication for Git.

Comment: This does not match the current version of Visual Studio Code (1.62.3). For instance, "Preferences" does not contain "Configuration" (or anything close to it). Can you add information for later versions of Visual Studio Code? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)