# Jenkins - using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials

Tags: jenkins

I've set up some credentials in Jenkins for bitbucket and double-checked the Credentials settings (e.g. logging in manually) however when I try it in Jenkins it just spins forever giving this output:

```
> git config remote.origin.url <bitbucket url> # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from <bitbucket url>
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials <bitbucket account email> Bitbucket
> git fetch --tags --progress <bitbucket url> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git fetch --tags --progress <bitbucket url> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note that the URL is fine when public. But when set to Private it simply fails with no output.

Is there anyway to debug this in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar issue, with Jenkins on a Windows server. I installed git with credentials manager and whenever it tried to checkout a private repository, it would wait for me to input credentials manually in the server. Disabling the git credential manager fixed it for me.

I already had an option to input credentials in the git plugin so didn't need a separate credentials manager.

Comment: Exactly, and here is how to do it: 
`git config --system --unset credential.helper ` More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-to-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows

Comment: @benButzer you are awesome!

Comment: Legend @BenButzer!!

Comment: @BenButzer alas, this did not work for me. Any other suggestions perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

This is on MacOSX.
I changed the Jenkins setting on Git path to /usr/local/git as well as unset the credential.helper using git config, both don't work.

Finally, the problem was resolved by creating a default keychain file for jenkins in ~jenkins/Library/Keychains folder.  Herewith is the steps...

- sudo su jenkins
- mkdir ~jenkins/Library/Keychains
- cd ~jenkins/Library/Keychains
- security create-keychain -p [pwd] ./Login.keychain
- security login-keychain -d user -s ./Login.keychain
- check default keychain setup properly security default-keychain
- git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/....git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

After that, the github userid/password is stored in jenkins default keychain and it will be used on jenkins build.

Answer (score 4):

> I had a similar issue, with Jenkins on a Windows server. I installed git with credentials manager and whenever it tried to checkout a private repository, it would wait for me to input credentials manually in the server. Disabling the git credential manager fixed it for me.

Actually, that should now (Q1 2021) work *without* having to disable the credential helper with Git 2.30.

"[`git credential`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e0f6ad2984918e316df9bd5bf6b90fe6e885beee/Documentation/git-credential.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential))</sup>' didn't honor the `core.askPass` configuration variable (among other things), which has been corrected with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021).

See [commit 567ad2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/567ad2c0f90fe63d1fde2c0269be8df17675148c) (15 Oct 2020) by [Thomas Koutcher (`koutcher`)](https://github.com/koutcher).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e0f6ad2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0f6ad2984918e316df9bd5bf6b90fe6e885beee), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/567ad2c0f90fe63d1fde2c0269be8df17675148c): load default config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Thomas Koutcher</sup>
> <sup>[jk: added test]</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King peff@peff.net</sup>
> Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano gitster@pobox.com
>
> Make [`git credential fill`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/567ad2c0f90fe63d1fde2c0269be8df17675148c/Documentation/git-credential.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential))</sup> honour the `core.askPass` variable.

---

As noted by [kymikoloco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196304/kymikoloco) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627269/jenkins-using-git-askpass-to-set-credentials/64758092?noredirect=1#comment123807793_64758092), upgrading to the latest (Nov. 2021) **[Git for Windows 2.34](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.34.0.windows.1)** seems enough to solve the issue.

Comment: Upgrading from 2.17.1 to 2.34.0 worked for me

Comment: @KymikoLoco Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on OSX. My issue was that Jenkins was using the wrong Git executable (I verified this by disabling the checkout step and adding `which git` before anything else).

I ran `which git` in terminal and copy-pasted the path into Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Git -> Path to Git executable. It worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

I had such problem with Jenkins on Windows 10. It always showed failure with permission denied error, code 128 returned by git.exe after **...GIT_ASKPASS for credentials step**. Changing **credential.helper** and env.variable **GIT_ASKPASS** did not help me at all, the same behaviour.

Then i checked up which git.exe in cmd **where git** and was suprised, it was  **SmartGit**'s internal one.

I changed it to **JGit** in Jenkins global settings and it works now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBfIi.png

Answer (score -1):

Its works for me!

1. Goto Dashboard --> configuration
2. Scroll down to find Git plugin

- input Global Config user.name Value: ex: jenkins
- input Global Config user.email Value ex: youremail@gmail.com

Answer (score -4):

you need to generate an SSH key from Git and add it to Bitbucket