# Git fatal: ArgumentNullException encountered

Tags: git, github, git-for-windows

I'm receiving the following error trying to push to the Github repo. I'm working on windows, repo is on GitHub.

Looks like some problem with the Credentials Manager, because after the error message, credentials is being requested again, and I can push my changes anyway, but the error is really annoying.

I know that GitHub no longer support TLS 1.0 and 1.1, only 1.2, that's why I updated to last version Git for Windows:

```
git --version
git version 2.17.0.windows.1
```

However it does not help much

UPDATE: Detailed STR

```
git commit --all -m"#ISSUE-123 Rename example dirs; added command-line handlers"
22 files changed, 501 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
git push https://<my_username>@github.com/<my_repo>.git #ISSUE-123
fatal: ArgumentNullException encountered.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
```

Of course, path and username are 100% correct

Comment: which error buddy ? when ? screenshot please ?

Comment: Sure mate, see update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue, looks like hard-to-reproduce problem with Git Credential Manager. First, I reinstalled Git and de-selected "Git Credential Manager for Windows" checkbox. Then I installed Credential Manager separately from the [Git page](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). Everything works fine now. Hope will be fixed in the next version for Windows

Answer (score 4):

To improve [Yuri S. Cherkasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707779/yuri-s-cherkasov) solution, you can directly remove "Git Credential Manager for Windows" by running :

```
git config --edit --system
```

And remove the following line :

```
helper = manager
```

Credits to [jez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178757/jez) from this post : [How to disable Git Credential Manager for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-to-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Bash treated the hash `#` as start of comment:

```
git push https://<my_username>@github.com/<my_repo>.git "#ISSUE-123"
```

Quote the string that contains the hash and the problem should go.

It doesn't seem to be a common practice to have hashes in branch names, however.

Comment: Never had any issue with the hash before. Quotation does not help

Comment: See the questions, I'm under Windows, hash does not treated as a comment