# Location of ~/.git-credentials file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, git

I searched but couldn't find the path of `~/.git-credentials` in my Windows 10 machine. [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) says that it stores username and password in plain-text in `~/.git-credentials`. I want to verify it by opening the file manually.

Comment: It's in your user `HOME` directory. `~` is Unix HOME

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is located at `%UserProfile%\.git-credentials`, which corresponds to `C:\Users\<username>\.git-credentials` (unless you've modified the registry to move your user's profile directory elsewhere).

Generally, `~` refes to the user's home directory on Linux, and many cross-platform tools which store data in `~` on Linux (including git) store their data in the user's home directory on Windows as well.

Comment: Or, if you modified the registry to change your user directory, `%UserProfile%\.git-credentials`

Comment: thanks bud, didn't know about ~ equivalent on windows

Answer (score 24):

On windows 10, git user credentials are now stored with the Credential Manager.

Comment: Is there a way to change that? Have it written to a user selected path?

Comment: @Royi, try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185202/277504. (Remove `helper = manager` from the git system-level config.)