# Unable to push to github: repository not found

Tags: windows, git, github

Whenever I try to push changes to a remote `github` repository from the command-line, I receive the following error:

```
> git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo.git' not found
```

(I've replaced org and repo name, but they are definitely the correct names).

I have checked I have write access to the repository. I'm able to create branches and write to files through the `github` website, and pull these changes back down locally.

I am authenticating with github using the [Git Credential Manager for Windows (GCM)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), and I have the following in gitconfig:

```
[credential]
    helper = manager
```

I'm running on Windows 10, git version 2.10.2.windows.1.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found They suggests adding the username to the url like: https://myusername@github.com/path_to/myRepo.git

Comment: Have you initialized your local git repo correctly using `git init` and added the remote `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git` ? 
Sorry if this is obvious

Comment: @SvinSimpe The repo was cloned from github, if I run `git remote show origin` it all looks to be set-up correctly.

Comment: @SebastianBerge tried `git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/path_to_myRepo.git` but still set the repository not found error.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was with Git Credential Manager, I deleted the saved credential from Windows through Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials. The next time I tried to push it popped up a dialog prompting for the github username and password. On entering these it seems to have sorted itself out.

Comment: Thank you! After fighting with this issue for hours, this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what branch you want to push to.

`-git push origin branchName`

[GitHub Docs: Pushing to a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the command suggest by SvinSimpe when you first `cd` into the directory where the branch is locally stored?

Comment: Yes, I was running the command from inside the directory. I have sorted it now, will post a response just in case others come across it too.