# Push files to Github

Tags: git, github

I cloned my repo on my laptop and followed the steps:

```
git add .

git commit -m "First commit"

git remote add origin (repository URL)

git push -u origin master
```

but for some reason, I get a fatal error telling me that the repo not found. What's the issue?

Comment: maybe you mis-typed the repo address

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: If you cloned the repo from yourself, you did not need to add the origin

Comment: After adding the remote origin, run `git remote -v` to see if your remote git address(es) is/are listed.

Comment: Is it a private repo ? I f yes , try removing the remote origin and re-adding it with your username and password credentials on the repo URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Push ERROR: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found)

Comment: @MichaelSolati, This is what I get:


`origin https://github.com/Flock1/Udacity/tree/master/Project%205 (fetch)`
`origin https://github.com/Flock1/Udacity/tree/master/Project%205 (push)`

Comment: Okay you're not pushing up to a git repo, your pushing up to the GitHub URL for viewing your repo. The repo URL should look like this `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Comment: @MichaelSolati, should I be doing something like this:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Comment: Yes, with username replaced with `Flock1` and REPOSITORY with `Udacity`. Based on your previous comments.

Comment: @MichaelSolati, got this:

`fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: Because the `origin` was assigned to the wrong URL. Read this to remove the remote https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote

Comment: @MichaelSolati, I removed it. Just one more question, I have folders in the repo. So how do I make sure that my files get uploaded to a specific folder?

Comment: If you created the `git` repo in a root directory of all the folders, then all of your sub folders will be tracked just fine.

Comment: Got this after pushing:
`error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Flock1/Udacity.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: So your remote is ahead of your local. Run `git pull` and resolve any conflicts that may have occurred. You should be able to push up then.

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta I have updated my answer to take into account your last error message

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the official GitHub "[Error: Repository not found](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/)" listing the main reasons:

- spelling
- permissions
- ssh access (that is, if you have used an ssh url)
- existence of the repo

In your case, the origin url is wrong:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

In your case:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Flock1/Udacity.git
```

That won't change anything about the repo: you can add an push.

That is: you clone a full repo, not a folder within the repo.

---

> ```
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Flock1/Udacity.git'  
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind 
>   hint: its remote counterpart
> ```

If your working tree is clean (meaning if `git status` reports there is no modification or untracked file), do:

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

That will replay your commits on top of the updated upstream remote repo.

Comment: Checked everything. Repo exists and I have cloned the repo on my laptop. So i think I'm good there.

Comment: If you have cloned the repo, you don't need the git remote add command. Check if you can push, assuming you are the owner of the repo.

Comment: When I said you don't need that command, I meant don't type it. If you do, you would get that error message.

Comment: Can't. It says reporistory not found:
`fatal: repository 'https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/tree/master/Project%205/' not found`

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta never mind: I have seen the comments above: I have eidted the answer accordingly.

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta When you clone, make sure to clone the repo, not a folder within the repo. The proper url for a repo is `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO`, not `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/tree/...`; this is Git, not Subversion.

Comment: When I run `git status`, I get the following in red color:

`modified:   solution (modified content)`

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta yes, you need to add and commit your current modification, before the pull --rebase

Answer (score 0):

After adding the remote origin, run `git remote -v` to see if your remote git address(es) is/are listed.

From there you should ensure that your `remote origin` url looks right. A remote url should look like `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`.

If you need to remove an incorrect `origin` and assign a new one you can remove that remote with the following command `git remote rm origin`

Comment: No need for rm/add: I have added the correct remote command in my answer.

Comment: @VonC Based my answer off of the convo I had with the OP in the comments of the question.

Comment: I know. I was having the very same conversion

Comment: So, something funny has happened. I followed your steps and for some reason, it pushed to github. When I checked, the commit is empty. Nothing got pushed for some reason. I'm trying to add files using `git add .` and when I check the status, I get this:
`On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: In your root folder try `git status` and post back the results

Comment: `On branch git_fix`
`Untracked files:`
  `(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)`

 `.gitignore`
 `Project 1/`
 `Project 2/`
 `Project 3/`
 `Project 5/.gitignore`
 `Project 5/Project 1/`
 `Project 5/Project 2/`
 `Project 5/Project 5/`

`nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)`

Comment: It sounds as if you possibly have a git repo inside of another git repo, which is causing some of the confusion. Your nested repo hasnt had any changes hence the `On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean`, but in the root folder you have the untracked files.