# How to commit my branch development to the git?

Tags: git, github

I have two branches in our repository.

```
 master
    dev
```

I got checkout from my **dev** branch. (#`git checkout -b origin/dev`) And I did some development locally. I want to commit that changes to that  **dev** branch.
I tried.

```
#git add .
#git commit -m "aa"
# git push
```

But getting fatal error. `repository 'https://github.com/lobdev/eps-portal.git/' not found`

When trying status

```
# git status
```

I get

```
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How can I commit to the dev branch?

I tried ;

```
 #git remote show origin
```

And getting;

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/lobdev/eps-portal.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/lobdev/eps-portal.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    dev    tracked
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    dev merges with remote dev
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    dev pushes to dev (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: Is your repository on GitHub private? Are you able to run `git fetch` without error?

Comment: check your git url.: git remote -v

Comment: @Tim .  I modified my question too. I have two branches in git repository. Master and dev. Here is what I see; git remote -v
origin https://github.com/lobdev/eps-portal.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/lobdev/eps-portal.git (push)

Comment: @Ryan git fetch didnt give any errors. I modified my quetsion too. I have two brances in git repository. Mastr and dev

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Push ERROR: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found)

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow no mine different

Comment: Looks like your `origin/dev` branch has some other commit on the top which you do not have on your local branch. `git fetch origin` and use next command to find the missing commit `git log origin/dev ^dev`. If you see any commit, then you can rebase your branch to get the latest changes from `origin/dev`. You can rebase your branch as `git rebase origin dev` and they try pushing the changes.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale Here are the outputs.(Note: Im the only one working on dev branch) #git fetch origin (NO OUTPUT)
yy-portal ratha$ git log origin/dev ^dev(NO OUTPUT)

Comment: little confused as to what your url should. be. lobdev/eps-portal.git or lyy/yy-portal.git. i suspect you need to correct your remote url. git clone <url> followed by git fetch origin master and git checkout -b dev should have gotten your master branch down and created a dev branch from it. "git checkout dev" : make changes, then "git add --all" , 'git commit -m "msg"' && "git push -u origin dev"  : should have pushed your dev branch with changes back up (only use -u switch the first push). Did you do this? Or did you fork the branch and clone the fork?

Comment: @Tim, In the question i provided correct URLs(earlier i edited with artbitary strings). URL is not an issue. I believe committing to a branch(ie:dev) is different way than committing to  master ?

Comment: @Ratha, looks like you do not have permission to push to this repository. Either get the required access or try forking this repository and push your changes to your fork. Then raise a `pull request` to main repository.

Comment: @ratha no, committing to dev and pushing won't be different from master. And you are not getting a 403, so i do not suspect its a permissions issue. Please review the steps i mentioned. interested to see 'git status', to see what state your local dev branch is in.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale Thanks forked and committed it works. Sorry Im new to git, never worked on a branch.

Comment: @Tim I forked the branch and commited as Rishikesh told. It works. I try your too.

Comment: Ok, cool. Check the documentation on setting upstream. So if using a fork, you dont really need to make a dev branch, you can use master of your fork. Or you can make a branch, doesnt matter. But you want to make it a habbit to merge upstream/master into your fork master, so your fork stays current. Then you make your changes, commit, push.. and do a pull request when ready for the app owner to merge your fork master (or dev) back into the main repo

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/

Comment: @Tim Thanks a lot. Will follow the best practices.

Answer (score -1):

Show all remotes:

```
git remote show
```

Inspect a remote:

```
git remote show origin
```

The remote url might be wrong (sometimes it's renamed to a different url).

Remove it:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Add updated url:

```
git remote add origin something.git
```

Comment: I have added few more details in my original question. Please check

Comment: git remote show origin  gives following; $ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/lobdev/eps-portal.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/lobdev/eps-portal.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    dev    tracked
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    dev merges with remote dev
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    dev pushes to dev (fast-forwardable) (I have edited my question with more information)

Comment: I do not want to remove origin . I want to update the dev branch