# Git clone works with Personal Access Token, but not Git push

Tags: git, github

I was wondering if anyone has faced this problem. I have created a Personal Access Token following [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line), and also gave full repo access to the access token.

I am able to clone the repo down via:

`git clone https://<Personal Access Token>@github.com/<Org name>/<Repo_name>.git`

But I am unable to push it gives me the error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
atal: repository 'https://<Personal Access Token>@github.com/<Org name>/<Repo_name>.git/' not found
```

Running `git remote -v` gives:

```
origin  https://<Personal Access Token>@github.com/<Org name>/<Repo_name>.git (fetch)
origin  https://<Personal Access Token>@github.com/<Org name>/<Repo_name>.git (push)
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Push ERROR: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found)

Comment: What command are you using to push? `git push ...`

Comment: Don't worry... I figured it out the account with the access token only had read access...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PO answered the question in a comment above:

> Don't worry... I figured it out the account with the access token only had read access...