# git clone error: remote: Not Found fatal: repository not found

Tags: git, github, windows-10, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to clone an organization's private git lab repository. I had access to it.

Command I used in windows 10: `git clone http://<git.organisation.com>/<user>/<repository_name>`

It is giving me this error

```
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository not found
```

I tried deleting credentials in Credential Manager, re-installed git, and tried the command in cmd, Git Bash, git GUI, windows PowerShell. None worked.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: *Not found* is not a problem of credentials. Can you access it from the web? and does your address end with `.git`?

Comment: No, I cannot access it from the web and yes it ends with .git.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Push ERROR: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found)

Comment: Are you in the organisation network? or is the network the repository resides in, accessible from outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, It's an access issue.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions...

Answer (score -1):

Login to your organization git, and please verify that are you able to find that repository or not.
This might be due to access issue.

Comment: When I login, I can't find that repo !  But one of my friend is able to clone the repo with same access rights.

Comment: Is he able to log in and see that repo. over there?
If he is, then ask him, weather he can see you as a member for that repo. or not.
It's better to verify that first.

Comment: Try solution given [here](https://github.community/t/fatal-repository-not-found/1180)

Comment: Yeah I will try. Thanks Jigar Moradiya :)