# git can't find repository to push to

Tags: git, github

I'm green as grass when it comes to git. Just started learning how to use it yesterday. Whenever I try to push a repository, I keep getting this

> error: `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/straywind/Demo.git/' not found`

This is what I did:

```
mkdir Demo
cd Demo
echo "#Demo" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/straywind/Demo.git
git push -u origin master
```

I then put in my username and password, and then i get the error message.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: If it is not private repository, this is normal. https://github.com/straywind/Demo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Push ERROR: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found)

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @Asocia: 404 error when trying to reach that page. I assume that repo exists and is private.

Comment: Please double check repo status, maybe it is "archived" or something. Please also [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63242089/edit) the remote platform where you are pushing to. Why do I recall bitbucket?

Comment: @Asocia It's not private. My github account says there are no repositories yet, private or otherwise.

Comment: @RiverreedWard You need to create that repository first then.

Comment: @Asocia, Thanks. Kinda a bonehead problem then. I assumed it would create it automatically, since none of the tutorials I looked at suggested I needed to create on on Github. Weird that tutorials will walk you through simple installation, but not mention that. My bad on any account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63242089/git-cant-fine-repository-to-push-to#comment111832243_63242089), this turned out to be a simple GitHub issue: you just had not yet created the repository over on GitHub.

(GitHub's requirement here may differ from other hosting sites, although this particular pattern is pretty common.)

As a side note, I'd recommend avoiding uppercase letters in repository names.  Parts of URLs are not case sensitive: GITHUB.COM, github.com, and GitHub.com all mean the same thing, for instance.  But *Git* names *are* case sensitive, and a repository named `demo` would differ from one named `Demo` on a Linux host, for instance.  Mixing case here is just inviting potential problems and you should pick one case and stick to it—probably lowercase since all-uppercase is a convention for implying that you are shouting.

Answer (score 0):

You might be making it a bit hard for yourself by starting with the `git init` and then [adding the remote](https://www.theserverside.com/video/How-to-use-the-git-remote-add-origin-command-to-push-remotely).

If you issue a `git clone` command first, the remote will automatically be set up for you and your first push will go much smoother. If you're working with GitHub, [create the GitHub repo](https://youtu.be/znRVAvQy5FU) first, clone, then do the GitHub push.

```
git clone https://github.com/cameronmcnz/github-made-easy.git
touch a.html
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think I've got the basics down now.