# Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote. flutter

Tags: android, flutter, github, open-source

I am trying to push my flutter project on Github. I get this error. can anyone please specify the actual reason why this happened?

```
 C:\Users\iumeedsaher\quiz_app_flutter>git push -u origin master 
 Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/iumeedsaher/.ssh/id_rsa': 
 ERROR:
 Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

[image]

Comment: Well it says that the repository is not found. Make sure it's typed correct and exists. `git remote -v` will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Push ERROR: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found)

Comment: Did you add SSH key to GitHub? Please look into the docs that you followed that correctly https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first in command line what your remote repository URL is.

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

It should be `git@github.com:<myGitHubAccount>/<myProject>`, with the case (uper/lowercase) correctly set in the URL.

As commented, this supposed you have registered your SSH public key to your GitHub account SSH settings page.
To check that, type (it should print a Welcome message):

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```