# Github actions - remote git push not working

Tags: git, github-actions

I'm using `github actions` to push some code in my other git repo.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Push remote
        run: |
          git config user.name "myusername"
          git config user.email "myusername@gmail.com"
          git remote set-url origin "https://myusername:$GIT_TOKEN@github.com/myusername/AnotherRepo"
          git add mytext.txt
          git commit -m "Pushing mytext with remote push"
          git push
```

`GIT_TOKEN` is set as repo secrets of the current git repo. In this token I've provided all permissions.

Yet I'm getting error:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myusername/AnotherRepo.git/' not found.
```

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116373/git-push-error-repository-not-found) it seems it is a permission issue.

But both of these repos belong to me so why am I getting this error.

If I try to push file in the same source repo (where git action is running) then there is no issue.

So there is no issue in the action yaml.

What am I missing?

PS. I've also tried with `${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}`

Comment: Are you sure `GIT_TOKEN` contains a personal access token? Docs on how to create one: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token . Also make sure the token has the correct permissions.

Comment: @Bjorn, I've followed this docs only & basically gave it all the permissions.

Comment: Does it work on your own computer? I.e. add the remote with token to a local repository, and try to push?

Comment: You can't use the secret directly in the workflow like this. You need to use the `${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}` stntax somewhere to retrieve the secret value. There are two ways to do it, or adding `env: GIT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}` at the step level to use it as you did in the run command, or using directly `${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}` in the step run command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push code in another repo inside your current repo's GHA you shall checkout your code in another folder (use `path` to achieve this) and use this folder to push your code (use `working-directory` to achieve this). E.g:

```
- name: Checkout repository B
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
      path: './folder-B'
      token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
- name: Push remote
  working-directory: './folder-B'
  run: |
      git config user.name "myusername"
      git config user.email "myusername@gmail.com"
      git remote set-url origin "https://myusername:$GIT_TOKEN@github.com/myusername/AnotherRepo"
      git add mytext.txt
      git commit -m "Pushing mytext with remote push"
      git push
```